# How can I keep a command I started from the shell running if I logout from the shell?

Tags: command-line

Which methods exist to keep a command that was started from shell on running after logging out from from shell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- To put the application into the background, use `&`:

  ```
  command &
  ```
- If you wish to close the terminal, and keep the application running, you can use several options: [`screen`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/screen) [image: Install screen],  [`dtach`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dtach) [image: Install dtach] and `nohup`.

  ```
  nohup command &
  ```
- Screen is helpful as you can re-start a session and dtach is fun as well.
- Look at the following links for more informations

  - **[Screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen)**
  - **[Dtach](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dtach)**

Comment: doesnt adding an `&` at the end of the command work too?

Comment: @Kaustubh-P using & is often a good habbit to close terminals via the 'exit' command, not hitting the X close button.& makes the command run in thebackground.But if the parent shell closes. that can still force the background programs to exit.

Answer (score 6):

A useful (bash?) command is `disown`. the nice thing about it is that it works for an **already running** job (by the way, you disown jobs, not processes, so you need to do a `ctrl-Z, bg` before running disown on your job. For example, imagine yourself doing the following:

```
local % ssh some.where.com
remote % verylongscript.sh
```

*Now* you realize that you need to go but don't want the script to be killed upon exiting, so you

```
ctrl-Z
remote % bg
remote % disown
remote % exit
local %
```

Now, on `remote`, your script is still running.

Answer (score 5):

Use the nohup command like this:

```
nohup gedit /home/user/file.txt &
```

Comment: How to even remove nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
nohup mycommand &
```

For example to bring up a VirtualBox virtual server I type the following in a remote shell (which I close then):

```
nohup VBoxHeadless --startvm "myvm" --vrdp=off &
```