# SSH programs terminates when closed

Tags: server, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i keep a command started from shell on running if i logout from shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18713/how-can-i-keep-a-command-started-from-shell-on-running-if-i-logout-from-shell)

When i ssh into my server and launches a program and then closes the SSH, the program closes to. How do i bypass this? The program is started with a shell script.

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
Ubuntu Server 12.04 32bit (doesn't support 64bit)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a program called `screen` on the remote machine.

Simply do the following:

- connect to the remote machine.
- Type `screen process_name` and replace process_name with the desired process.
- You can later open this process with the command: `screen -r`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Will this pause the program when i disconnect? cause i wan't to be able to start my Teamspeak 3 server remotly

Comment: It won't. `screen` is a "terminal multiplexer", you can leave it by terminating what you start, or my *detaching*. Detaching here is the key, `screen` keeps running in the background, but with no associated terminal, so the program does not terminate when you disconnect. `screen` is even a common choice to leave stuff running on a remote computer to which you connect through SSH once in a while.

Comment: @Emil: I see that you haven't marked the question as answered. Are you still facing problems ?